# How to add a virtualhost of a domain other than default folder?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have a server (OS is CentOS) which has Apache. My default folder is `/var/www/html/`. When I add my domain this folder it works.

But when I do this in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /space/www/htdocs

    <Directory /space/www/htdocs>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog logs/mydomain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mydomain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

403 happens. What should I do?

Comment: Is your `/space/www/htdocs` folder has same permissions & ownership as `/var/www/html`

Comment: Yes both are root:root.

Comment: root:root, but permissions ? it must be 755

Comment: Yes all directories are 755 and files are 644.

Comment: try `<Directory "/space/www/htdocs">`  instead of `<Directory /space/www/htdocs>`

Comment: @salton I tried double quotation marks too. It's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup seems ok.

but you may need to modify the SELinux file context database, or change the SELinux type of certain file.

Run the following command,

> semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/space(/.*)?'
>
> restorecon -vR /space

by default the file content of your web server is public_content_t, so you need to change into httpd_content_t to allow web server the contents out.

Comment: First of all thank you very very much. My OS is CentOS and it doesn't have `semanage` by default. So I istalled policycoreutils-python. That way I could use your commands. I've been using *nix amateurishly for 10 years and never heard this type of file permission. I want to learn more about this. What is it?

Comment: Its comes under the topic of SELinux (Security Enhanced Linux).

Refer the link for more info,
http://drupalwatchdog.com/2/2/apache-selinux